# Proper function defining structure?

Tags: scala

I don't really understand the order in which functions and parts of functions need to be laid out in order for scala to understand my function will eventually output the correct type instead of a unit. I have made comments (line 7 and last line) for what eclipse is telling me on those lines. Any insight into the compiler is much appreciated.

```
object braces {
 def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {

    def rightBraces(chars: List[Char], openCount: Int, closeCount: Int): Boolean = {
        if (!chars.tail.isEmpty) {
            if (chars.head == '(') rightBraces(chars.tail, openCount + 1, closeCount)
            /*type mismatch;  found   : Unit  required: Boolean*/else if (chars.head == ')') rightBraces(chars.tail, openCount, closeCount + 1)
        }
        else {
            if ((chars.head == '(')&&(openCount == (closeCount - 1))) true
            else if ((chars.head == ')')&&(openCount == (closeCount + 1))) true
            else (openCount == closeCount)
        }
    }

    def wrongBrace(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
     if (!chars.tail.isEmpty) {
         if (chars.head == ')') false
         else if (chars.head == '(') rightBraces(chars.tail, 1, 0)
         else wrongBrace(chars.tail)
     }
     else false
    }

    wrongBrace(chars)

 }
}//Missing closing brace `}' assumed here
```

Comment: the problem is that you not provided else clause with value if both conditions are false (`if` and `else if`, lines 6 and 7 respectivly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

> ```
>     if (!chars.tail.isEmpty) {
>         if (chars.head == '(') rightBraces(chars.tail, openCount + 1, closeCount)
>         else if (chars.head == ')') rightBraces(chars.tail, openCount, closeCount +1)
>     }
> ```

For the inner if block, there is a possibility that neither if nor else if evaluates to true. In that case no value is returned and compiler returns a Unit by default.

So you must provide a default case within an **else block** or change the **else if** to an **else** if that's appropriate.